# How to access angular component from 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, deezer

I'm building web app which uses Deezer player by official JS SDK. The problem I met is that I cannot access my Angular component from Deezer event subscription. Arrow function doesn't understand context of `this`, so I cannot call my component's methods and pass values to them. What is correct way to achieve that?

**app.component.ts**

```
// ...

declare var DZ;

// ...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    currentTrack: any = null;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        DZ.init({
            appId  : '8',
            channelUrl : 'https://developers.deezer.com/examples/channel.php',
            player : {
                onload : this.onPlayerLoaded
            }
        });
    }

    onPlayerLoaded() {
        DZ.player.playAlbum(302127);

        DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', console.log);
        DZ.Event.subscribe('current_track', (response) => {
            // I would like to pass response.track to setCurrentTrack() there
        });
    }

    setCurrentTrack(track) {
        this.currentTrack = track;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
// ...

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://e-cdns-files.dzcdn.net/js/min/dz.js"></script>
</head>

// ...
```

Comment: Are you not able to call `this.setCurrentTrack(response.track)` inside the subscription?

Comment: @HariniP nope. It tries to call setCurrentTrack of event subscription

Comment: Can you `.bind(this)` on your `player.onload` config?

Comment: That was slightly cryptic. so do `DZ.init({player : {onload: this.onPlayerLoaded.bind(this)} })`

Comment: @LostJon yes, this worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to help other individuals, you should `.bind(this)` to your function call because its likely that `this` is referring to the DZ context and no longer your class:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    DZ.init({
        appId  : '8',
        channelUrl : 'https://developers.deezer.com/examples/channel.php',
        player : {
            onload : this.onPlayerLoaded.bind(this)  //Fix right here
        }
    });
}
```